# Names of positions?

Tags: poker-theory

Reading [What I did was right?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1417/what-i-did-was-right) I see reference to 
Hijack, Cut-Off, and Villain.  I assume these are positions?  Which positions?

Comment: It's a valid question but has already had numerous answers dedicated to it. Check the link I referenced. Also, before asking a question, use the search function (Top of page, I suggest "Position" or something similar for this one). You'll usually find what you're looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hijack is one place before the cut off.

The cut off is one place before the dealer button

Villain is not a position at all. It refers to the person that you are playing against. You are the Hero and they are the villian.

More info on positions can be found here:

[Poker position nicknames](http://poker.lifetips.com/faq/102720/0/what-are-the-nicknames-for-positions-around-the-table/index.html)